# redux getState() doesn't return the updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, getstate

The problem that made me stuck for days is that although my redux devtool shows the successful state update without any kind of mutation and with successful View component rerender, but when I call getState() it always return the initial state and doesn't care about updated state! anyone who knows what could make this kind of situation pls help me.

I use react-redux and redux-thunk

action.js

```
export function test(data) {
  return {
    type: 'TEST',
    data
  };
}

export function testFunc(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(test(data))
    console.log('GLOBAL STATE IS :', store.getState() )
  };
}
```

reducer.js

```
export default function peopleReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        test: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Page01.js

```
componentDidUpdate(){
   console.log('get state = ', store.getState())
}

....

<TouchableHighlight 
   underlayColor={"#0e911b"}
   onPress={() => {
   this.props.testing('test contenttttt !!!!')            
    }}
 >
   <Text style={styles.title}>ACTION</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>



function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    people: state.people,
    planets: state.planets,
    test: state.test
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { 
    getPeople: () => dispatch(getPeopleFromAPI()), 
    getPlanets: () => dispatch(getPlanetsFromAPI()), 
    testing: data => dispatch(testFunc(data)) };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Where an how exactly are you using getState, can you show a sample code snippet where you see this problem

Comment: don't see you using getState in the above snippet

Comment: at the Page01.js

Comment: Where exactly, its not in the code that you have mentioned

Comment: Sorry, I mean in action.js right after dispatch

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to use `getState()` in action file, you need to use it from store directly, rather you can get it as the second parameter to the inner function along with dispatch when using `redux-thunk`

```
export function testFunc(data) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(test(data))
    console.log('GLOBAL STATE IS :', getState())
  };
}
```

also your updated state will not be seen right after you dispatch the action since redux-state update happens asynchronously. You should rather check it in the `componentDidUpdate` function of the component where you are using the state.

Also, in order to get the updated state using `store.getState()` you need to subscribe to the state change like

```
// Every time the state changes, log it
// Note that subscribe() returns a function for unregistering the listener
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log(store.getState())
)
```

and you can `unsubscribe` by calling

```
unsubscribe()
```

You may read more about it **[here](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#subscribe(listener))**

However when you use connect, you don't need to use `store.getState()` in the component, you can use `mapStateToProps` function to get the state values.

Comment: Dude I tried `componentDidUpdate` too, but still the problem exists!

Comment: unsubscribe() returns undefined. Where can I use it?

Comment: you don't need to get its return value, also with react, you would not use store.subscribe but connect

Comment: Thank you, u helped to figure out the right way. appreciating

Comment: @MrxRinc , glad to have helped