# Component not rerender after action being dispatched and reduced

Tags: reactjs, redux

i want to make a counter Component when i learning in react and redux now.
so i want to change the eval input and then i will click the resolve input,and the end show the resolve to component2.but when i clicked,the resolve was changed in reducer and actions (i was consoled the resolve) , but had not change in component2,why?my English is not good,thanks...

this is my full code:

actions.js

```
export function DO_COUNT(resolve) {
  return {
    type: 'DO_COUNT',
    payload: resolve
  }
}
```

reducer.js

```
import actions from '../actions'    
export default (state = { resolve: 0 }, actions) => {
      switch (actions.type) {
        case 'DO_COUNT':
          console.log({
            ...state,
            resolve: actions.payload
          })
          return {
            ...state,
            resolve: actions.payload
          }
          break
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from '../reducers'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools())

export default store
```

my component1:Counter.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styleObj from './style.less'
import store from '../../store'
import { DO_COUNT, CHANGE_EVAL } from '../../actions'

export default class Counter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      num1: 0,
      num2: 0,
      myEval: '+'
    }
  }

  changeEval = e => {
    this.setState({
      myEval: e.target.value
    })
  }

  changeNum1 = e => {
    // let _target = e.target.dataset.target
    let value = e.target.value
    this.setState(
      {
        num1: value
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state)
      }
    )
  }
  changeNum2 = e => {
    // let _target = e.target.dataset.target
    let value = e.target.value
    this.setState(
      {
        num2: value
      },
      () => {
        console.log(this.state)
      }
    )
  }

  doCount = () => {
    let resolve = eval(
      [this.state.num1, this.state.num2].join(this.state.myEval)
    )
    store.dispatch(DO_COUNT(resolve))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styleObj.counterBox}>
        <input type="number" onInput={this.changeNum1} data-target="num1" />
        <select onChange={this.changeEval}>
          <option defaultValue="+">+</option>
          <option value="-">-</option>
          <option value="*">*</option>
          <option value="/">/</option>
        </select>
        <input type="number" onInput={this.changeNum2} data-target="num2" />
        <input type="button" value="=" onClick={this.doCount} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

my component2:Container.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styleObj from './style.less'
import store from '../../store'

export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return <h1 className={styleObj.content}>{store.getState().resolve}</h1>
  }
}
```

and image:

[image]

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892456/redux-getstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state/49892910#49892910

Comment: Its not a bug with redux but an issue in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start).

The problem is your `Container` component is not being notified when the store's state changes. You can do this manually by hooking into lifecycle methods and setting state, but this is what `react-redux` already does (in a more optimized way).